# Text scrolls outside of UITextView object

Tags: iphone, ios, interface-builder, uitextfield

I have some text in a UITextView object. The issue I'm having is that the text scrolls outside of the UITextField box. How would I go about fixing this?

thanks for any help

```
textBG.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero;
```

where 'textBG' is the name of my UITextView

Comment: UITextView or UITextField? Decide and also post some code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

USE this in textViewShouldBeginEditing method it will help you

```
YourTextViewObject.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero;
```

Comment: Can I add this as a property to the UITextField on viewDidLoad?     textBG.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero;
I don't have a textViewShouldBeginEditing method

Comment: you can put this property in any UITextField delegete method or viewDidLoad

Comment: I've added  textBG.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero; to the viewDidLoad . The text still scrolls out of the bounds of the UITextView though. The UITextField is not editable' (parameter set in Interface Builder). Any idea where I might be going wrong? thanks